# How to remove the email in SP site?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

How to remove the email id from the SP site i.e, in the given below image with yellow marked line?[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the approaches could be that you can put below CSS somewhere in your global CSS files or in the Master Page:

```
.o365cs-me-userEmail {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This will hide the Email Id of the user.

Comment: Thanq so much SlackerAmit. Its working...